# Is there a way to upload using blueimp from bootstrap dialog?

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I'm using blueimp jQuery file upload and also bootstrap dialog (https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/), is there a way to upload from a bootstrap dialog button (BootstrapDialog.show) using blueimp? Can't seem to figure out a way to create a jQuery selector on a bootstrap dialog button and hook it to a fileupload.

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern at this moment is to create a jQuery selector on a button in a bootstrap dialog, try below:

```js
BootstrapDialog.show({
 title: 'Example',
    message: 'Write your example here.',
    buttons: [{
     id: 'btn-close',
     label: 'Close',
        action: function(dialog) {
         dialog.close();
        }
    }],
    onshown: function(dialog) {
      // This is a jQuery object
     var $btnClose = dialog.getButton('btn-close');
      $btnClose.hide();
    }
});
```

In this example you can get the button by id via getButton() method of the dialog instance, the returned object is the button wrapped with jQuery.

A jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ubx2mbmz/1/

You can also do similar in a traditional jQuery fashion:

```js
BootstrapDialog.show({
 title: 'Example',
    message: 'Write your example here.',
    buttons: [{
     label: 'Close',
        action: function(dialog) {
         dialog.close();
        }
    }],
    onshown: function(dialog) {
     var $btnClose = dialog.getModalFooter().find('button');
      $btnClose.hide();
    }
```

Another jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/7ftsc50n/1/